# How to check and then remove stationarity and autocorrelation from time series data?

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity

I have a time-series data with high level of non-stationarity and autocorrelation problem. How shall I remove this problem using R?

The existing regression results are as follows:

```
Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.82702 -0.39891 -0.06679  0.12791  2.36715 


Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)      -1.620e-01  3.161e-01  -0.513   0.6126  
RailGodsTrnsprt1  2.651e-06  1.239e-05   0.214   0.8323  
RoadDnstyL1       7.408e-10  7.998e-09   0.093   0.9269  
SecndryScholL1   -3.767e-02  8.034e-02  -0.469   0.6431  
TertryScholL1     2.098e-01  1.683e-01   1.247   0.2236  
PrmryScholL1      8.811e-02  4.169e-02   2.114   0.0443 *
MobiFixdL1       -6.145e-01  1.915e+00  -0.321   0.7509  
TFR2              1.043e-02  1.579e-01   0.066   0.9478  
---

    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.7175 on 26 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.1998, Adjusted R-squared: -0.01559 
F-statistic: 0.9276 on 7 and 26 DF, p-value: 0.5019
```

Comment: Difference the data: https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/1

Comment: Title does not match body text (in the title you're "removing *stationarity*", in the body text the problem is *non*-stationarity). Please make them consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Differencing the series can help you in removing the non-stationarity.

Three types of differencing are possible:

1. Random walk differencing (First order) `[y(t) = x(t) - x(t-1)]`

   `diff(ts)`
2. Second order differencing `[z(t) = y(t) - y(t-1)]`

   `diff(ts, differences = 2)`
3. Seasonal differencing `[y(t) = x(t) - x(t - NoofSeasons)]`

   `diff(ts, lag = NoofSeasons)`

KPSS-test or ADF test can help you check if you differenced series has reached stationarity.

The null hypothesis for KPSS-test is that the series is stationary. It is preferable that you accept the null hypothesis if `p-value > 0.05`.

If your series reaches stationarity on both random walk and seasonal differencing, then preference will be given to seasonal differencing.

---

If you wish to check the order of differencing and seasonal differencing are required to make the series stationary, you can try the following code:

`ns <- nsdiffs(cooltemp)
if(ns > 0) {
  xstar <- diff(x,lag=frequency(x),differences=ns)
} else {
  xstar <- x
}
nd <- ndiffs(xstar)
if(nd > 0) {
  xstar <- diff(xstar,differences=nd)
}`

Source: [Hyndman, R. J., & Athanasopoulos, G. (2016). 8.1 Stationarity and differencing. In Forecasting: principles and practice. Heathmont: OTexts.](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/1)